# 3rd party messaging apps with random silent notifications problem

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, skype, silent-mode

I am having a weird issue. I am on Android 10 on my LG G6 and I haven't installed any doze control app or greenify type apps etc on my phone but whenever I receive any message on 3rd party apps like Whatsapp or Skype etc, many of notifications arrive on time but some of the messages arrive with no vibration and no sound like silent notifications. I haven't set any DND or anything. It's just clean install rom and I have also faced this issue at my official stock ROM Android 9. Same behaviour recorded in that as well. For testing I captured notifications and what I saw is some of the messages comes via silent channelID which is very strange for me as no settings applied. It's all random messages and same behaviour when I am using my phone so I believe it's not doze level thing. I am attaching screenshots of notifications log, please guide me what's wrong going on here. Thanks.

**Screenshots:** https://postimg.cc/gallery/G3Tbjcg

Answer (score 1):

The same issue on Galaxy Note 9, observed this issue in Nov 2018 but no resolution. The same issue in One Plus also. Very difficult to say whether it is an Android issue or applications issue.

Found this issue in [Android Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139837594), Google is working on this, although I have observed this issue in Android 8, 9, 10.

Comment: Thank you, so its not me only.